# MS Access Inventory and Auto Increment Values

Tags: ms-access, inventory-management

I'm fairly new to MS Access, but I'm trying to make a user friendly database to maintain an inventory of blood products.

I need to track a few different points of information.

DIN

Blood Type

Product Type

Expiration Date

I've already figured out a system to add products to a table using a form, but right now it's not very specific to my needs.

To increase tracking capability I wanted to be able to assign new inventory items to different rack #s and storage units. I have 15 different storage units and I have literally hundreds of racks I could be filling.

So what I'm having trouble with is streamlining the process of assigning my units to different racks incrementally. I have an excel spreadsheet that does this, but it's not friendly to the end user.

So what I'd like to do is have my form accept barcode scans from the product which contains all the information I need except for the rack # and position in the rack. The idea is that I want to be able to use the form to put the Rack # in and then have the form automatically increment the slot in the rack as I scan them in.

I already know how to have default values carry over from the last form so I don't need to retype the rack # or freezer # as I fill the rack.

The format I'm going for is 1-1, 1-2, 2-1, 2-2 and so on until I reach position 8-2. Each rack holds 16 units. So I'd like for the slot # to autoincrement up to 8-2 then reset and clear the rack # field.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply increment a number by 1 for each reading.

```
Dim n As Long
Dim Position As String

n = n + 1
Position = (((n - 1) \ 2) Mod 8) + 1 & "-" & ((n - 1) Mod 2) + 1
```

Or, not using a number but reading the last Position:

```
n = Val(Split(LastPosition, "-")(0)) * 2 + Val(Split(LastPosition, "-")(1)) - 1
Position = (((n - 1) \ 2) Mod 8) + 1 & "-" & ((n - 1) Mod 2) + 1
```

Edit:

If you haven't done already, add an *AutoNumber* field to the table names, say, **Id**.

Create a function like this:

```
Public Function RackPosition(ByVal Number As Long) As String

    Dim Index       As Long
    Dim Position    As String

    ' Avoid zero and negative numbers.
    Index = Abs(Number) + 1

    Position = (((Index - 1) \ 2) Mod 8) + 1 & "-" & ((Index - 1) Mod 2) + 1

    RackPosition = Position

End Function
```

Then, in your form, include a textbox to display the rack position using this expression as *ControlSource*:

```
=IIf(IsNull([Id]),Null,RackPosition(Nz([ID],0)))
```

Comment: Do I put this in AfterUpdate or BeforeUpdate? Because I'm not sure that it's going to read this correctly.

Comment: That's up to you. Somehow you must either have the number of scannings or the last position, so the code doesn't read anything, only generates the next position from the value you pass to it.

Comment: I wish I could send you my database so you can see what I mean.

Comment: Well, you don't tell much about your form, but the approach in the edited answer should work.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PsglSJTEdEfjwz8P2s55ESR7l10pVr3B/view?usp=sharing

I scrubbed it for potentially sensitive information to give you an idea of how I intended it to be used.

Answer (score 0):

This is what to do:

1. Table: Change the data type of *Freezer* and *Rack* to *Number, Integer*
2. Form: Adjust the three textboxes, Freezer, Rack, and Position to be rught aligned
3. Module: Adjust to read like this:

-

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function RackPosition(ByVal Number As Long) As String
    Dim Index       As Long
    Dim Position    As String

    ' Avoid zero and negative numbers.
    Index = Abs(Number) + 1

    Position = (((Index - 1) \ 2) Mod 8) + 1 & "-" & ((Index - 1) Mod 2) + 1

    RackPosition = Position

End Function
```

4. Form module: Adjust like this:

-

```
Private Sub SetPosition()

    Const Positions As Integer = 16

    Dim Number      As Integer
    Dim Criteria    As String

    If Nz(Me!Freezer.Value, 0) + Nz(Me!Rack.Value, 0) = 0 Then
        ' No rack data.
    ElseIf IsNull(Me!Position.Value) Then
        ' Calculate next available position.
        Criteria = "[Freezer] = " & Me!Freezer.Value & " And [Rack] = " & Me!Rack.Value & " And [Position] Is Not Null"
        Number = DCount("*", "Blood Inventory (Raw)", Criteria)
        If Number >= Positions Then
            MsgBox "This rack is full", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Position"
        Else
            Me!Position.Value = RackPosition(Number)
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Freezer_AfterUpdate()

    SetPosition

End Sub

Private Sub Text42_AfterUpdate()

    SetPosition

End Sub
```

Now, when Freezer and Rack is entered, Position is filled out automatically.